# Custom Validation Attribute Always Returns IsValid==true

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a simple custom validation attribute working, but can't see what I am missing.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CustomValAttribute :ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class TestModel
{
   [CustomVal]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I try to validate:

```
var test = new TestModel (){ Name = "test" };
 ValidationContext contx = new ValidationContext(test, null, null);
 var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
 Console.WriteLine(Validator.TryValidateObject(test, contx, results));
```

But the result is always true, then I found that my custom validator's `IsValid` method is never being called by the `Validator`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(test, contx, results, true);
```

If last parameter is not set to `true`, `Validator` is only checking properties with `RequiredAttribute` (and only validates using that attribute, ignoring other attributes).